# REST API And Error Codes - No Message

Tags: api, rest-api

I'm writing some code which inserts a new post and some postmeta using AngularJs and the REST API.

I'm filtering the rest_pre_insert{postype} hook which is allowing me to throw an error when the required meta is not part of the request data. I've assigned a message but the console in Chrome only shows the error code, no message. I could really do with showing the user this message, can anyone help me get it? I've been tracing the various methods through several files and I cannot work out why the message doesn't get returned to the browser. This is what my error looks like;

`return new WP_Error( 'rest_no_event_date', __( 'You must enter a date for this event.' ), array( 'status' => 401 ) );`

Also, I'm not sure what code I should use. I know 404, 403 etc..but what code would be appropriate for "*you can't do that mate!*"..?

Many thanks, Dan

--- EDIT ---

I found out that I was using deprecated code in my Angular script and I now have access to the error message text. Unfortunately the console is still looking a 400/bad request error which I cannot resolve. I'm going to do some further testing and see if WP returns the same error when another post parameter is missing. I can't work out if WP of AngularJs is causing the issue!

Comment: You used `rest_pre_insert{postype}` or `rest_pre_insert_{postype}`?

Comment: 400 would be a good code... as "incorrect/unknown/missing parameter" message...

Comment: @Dan I've got the hook right, don't worry! The code works, it just comes though with an error and the code, no message.

Comment: @Random Thanks for clarifying. I've not had to do my own error codes before...every day's a school day.